# Core updates and module updates: Does order matter?

Tags: 6, updating

I inherited a badly out-of-date Drupal 6 multi-site instance.  There is only the production instance. (yeah, that gives me a warm-fuzzy!)

Many modules are several versions behind and the core is several versions behind.

Does the order in which I perform the updates matter?  I'm thinking update core first, then update the modules, but I'm just not sure.

Anyone care to advise?

Answer (score 1):

Order does matter.

Sadly, it's hard to tell exactly *how* it will matter in your situation. **If you can, make a dev copy of this site** and experiment on it. I would either go with core-first or with all at once. But that's my intuition, and actual tests on a copy of actual site matters much more.

Usually it's OK to jump all versions in-between the one you have and most recent one. For modules, sometimes, rarely, it's good to use most-recent minor version and don't install next major version at all (if both are maintained), or install most-recent minor and then update major. Sadly, it's different for each module, so fastest thing would be to update everything straight to the recent version, and see if / what broke. Of course, this is only feasible on a dev copy, not production.

Comment: Thanks - that is what I was thinking too.  A follow-on related question would be if I should apply the most-recent CORE update (even though there are about 9 versions in-between) or should I apply each core update separately until it's completely up to date?

Comment: @MzEllie feel free to edit this into your question, and I'll add this part to my answer.